# SQL Replacing COUNT(*) with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a query that finds a user with a given `id` and returns a username and a int whether a entry with given id exists in the table `x`.

```
SELECT 
    username
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE x.id = users.id) inTableX
FROM users
WHERE users.name = @name;
```

Column `x.id` is a unique key and such inTableX will return 0 if there is none and 1 if it does exist. So the current is working but my current assumption is that there is a better keyword to use which will tell mssql to stop iterating / searching over once it has found a row / entry that satisfies the WHERE condition. As table `x` has a lot of entries I am hoping that the solution will improve performance of this query.

Comment: If it's a 1-1 relationship why not use a `LEFT JOIN`? Also, do you have any indexes?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: If `x.id` has a unique index and it's true that there's always at most one row, then replacing `COUNT` with `EXISTS` is unlikely to bring any benefit. The optimizer is smart enough to seek the index regardless. If you have reason to complain about the performance, [share the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and let's see what's what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the equivalent version with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    users.name,
    case when exists (select 1 FROM x WHERE x.id = users.id) then 1 else 0 end
FROM users
WHERE users.name = @name;
```

It will return 1 if there is a row with that id in `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
SELECT 
    username,
    CASE WHEN x.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS inTableX
FROM users LEFT JOIN x
     ON x.id = users.id
WHERE users.name = @name;
```